# How to close an eventChannel when a certain action comes along

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I have an eventChannel for listening to webSockets, this works fine.

I also want to listen to an action `USER_LOGGED_OUT` and close the channel.

I'm closing the channel from within the channel by emitting `END` in case of a socket error or socket closing, but how do I do this based on external actions?

This is the channel loop:

```
export function* websocketWatcher() {
  const tokenResponse = yield take(RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN);
  const accessToken = tokenResponse.payload.data.access_token;

  const channel = yield call(createWebsocketChannel, accessToken);
  try {
    while (true) {
      const action = yield take(channel);
      yield put(action);
    }
  } finally {
    console.log('Websocket channel terminated');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering this myself..

I just found `channel.close()` in the docs. Don't know how I missed that. I solved it with a race between the channel (incoming socket data) and the logged out action.

```
export function* websocketWatcher() {
  const tokenResponse = yield take(RECEIVE_USER_TOKEN);
  const accessToken = tokenResponse.payload.data.access_token;

  const channel = yield call(createWebsocketChannel, accessToken);
  try {
    while (true) {
      const { logoutAction, socketAction } = yield race({
        logoutAction: take(USER_LOGGED_OUT),
        socketAction: take(channel)
      });

      if (logoutAction) {
        channel.close();
      } else {
        yield put(socketAction);
      }
    }
  } finally {
    console.log('Websocket channel terminated');
  }
}
```

Comment: what does finally do? When it is terminated?